# How to translate WP Blog (search, category etc.)?

Tags: plugins, themes, translation

We are running a site with WordPress and WooCommerce. We have used WPML to have the option of adding multiple languages.

Now we want to get rid of WPML :)

We have deleted it and set the WP language to "formal German". Everything looks good (plugins will be translated via loco translate).

But I cannot manage to translate our default WP blog. There are still buttons, search forms etc. that are not translatable (or at least I did not find were to look).

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you have bought a theme you should have support for other languages. See the chapter [Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) in the theme developer handbook for more information, or e.g. more specific on translation functions like [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) the Code Reference.

If you independently developed a theme, you probably forgot about this element. If not, check if your theme not have strings in theme without `__()`, if it is true, you should add all strings to functions like this – see above linked resource for an overview.

Furthermore, the Theme Handbook has an informative chapter on [how to localize](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/), with information about logic behind it and tools to use, you might find interesting.

Comment: Hi thanks! I've checked with the theme maker and found the POT File. But not sure where to put the PO/MO file afterwards. I've opened a ticket with them. unless one of you could help?

Comment: Hi! There you have a good tutorial for this issue https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-theme/